# Is there a GUI that I can use to create XML documents based on my schema?

Tags: xml, user-interface

I want to create a simple graphical user interface to allow non-technical users to create an XML file without having to manually edit the XML source. Ideally I'd like a drag and drop interface, but failing that, anything really. The contents of the XML file are similar to an encoded flow chart of a binary tree, so maybe something like Visio, with a save as xml option? Here's a quick sample of the XML output that is required:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<steps>
  <step id="1" type="prompt">
    <prompt>
      Welcome.
    </prompt>
    <next>1.1</next>
  </step>
  <step id="1.1" type="question">
    <prompt>
      Do you have what you need?
    </prompt>
    <yes>1.2</yes>
    <no>1.1.1</no>
  </step>
...
</steps>
```

Are there any existing tools out there that you can recommend for this purpose? Ideally open-source or with a free personal license, but I'm interested in hearing about all options.

Thanks,

David

Comment: Is it a web (HTML) interface you're interested in?

Comment: It doesn't matter if it's web or desktop - I'm interested in both.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A google for "XML Editors" yields a long list, [this was at the top.](http://www.altova.com/xml-editor/) (Altova XML editor) I'm sure if you googled "Open Source XML Editors" you'd find some too.

Allow me to mention that XCode has one built in. ;)

Comment: Hmm, I was complicating my Google search unnecessarily. Cheers!

Comment: In the fine art of Google-fu, less is more, young grasshopper.

Answer (score 2):

[Xopus](http://xopus.com) is a browser based XML editor designed for non-technical users. You can feed it your XML file and an XSD. Create an XSL to render the XML like a tree and you're good to go.

If you take a look at the [Rich Text Demo](http://xopus.com/demo/rich-text) and scroll down to the OrgChart, you can see how you can edit tree like content in Xopus.

Disclaimer: I work at Xopus.

Comment: @Laurens: you should admit that you're associated with Xopus, or you'll be considered a spammer.

Comment: I only respond if I genuinely think someone can benefit from our software. I have no interest in hiding my affiliation with Xopus.

Comment: thanks for the edit - and you changed your name, too!

Comment: @John: You're welcome. Thanks for the un-down-vote!

Answer (score 1):

[Tool4Py.com](http://tool4py.com/) that's what you mean [cfgpie.info](http://cfgpie.info/) or [wixpie.com](http://wixpie.com) came from there.

Answer (score 0):

"[XAmple XML Editor](http://www.felixgolubov.com/XMLEditor/) project introduces a java Swing based XML editor that analyzes a given schema and then generates a document-specific graphical user interface. Unlike other XML editors, the XAmple XML editor GUI exposes not just a tree representation of the XML document but rather a logical combination of the XML document and respective XML Schema. The user interface of the XML editor is highly logical and intuitively comprehensible. To be able to prepare valid XML documents of significant complexity, a user is not required to be familiar with XML and XML Schema languages and to have any a-priori knowledge about the documents structural requirements."

I've tried it and even my non-technical boss likes it.

Answer (score 0):

The people of http://WixPie.com made a generic xml editor the they demonstrated some months ago. With there tools you can create a xml task and assign tabs with folders and grids..and ask the user for input.

but at the moment the only project that i know that is based on that is wixpie.

Pieter

Comment: So what is your question?

Comment: @rebolek — isn't this an answer?

Comment: That is an answer and a valid one. Voted up!